# How to read files in ExecuteStreamCommand processor in NiFi

Tags: python, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, apache-nifi

My end goal is to mask the data in one particular file. I want to move files from one place to another. During this transfer process, I have to mask the data using a Python script. So, I designed below flow:

```
GetFile > ExecuteStreamCommmand > PutFile
```

I designed one `Python` script using `pandas`. I am running this `NiFi` on Virtual Machine created on `Google Cloud Platform` where I have installed `Python-2.7` and `NiFi-1.9.1`. Below is my Pandas code:

```
import pandas as pd
readFile = pd.read_csv("/path",sep=" ",header=None)
readFile.columns = ['IP']
readFile['IP'] = readFile['IP'].replace(regex='((?<=[0-9])[0-9]|(?<=\.)[0-9])',value='X')
readFile.to_csv("/path", sep=' ')
```

I have below doubts:
1) Using getFile processor I am passing the file in the queue to the next processor i.e ExecuteStreamCommand processor.
2) Also, in my Python code, I am trying to read the data from the same input directory that was passed in the GetFile processor but now the file has been moved to the queue between getfile > executestreamcommand. So how will it read it?
3) After the python script is executed how can I use a putFile processor to save it back at some other place?

I am new to NiFi so trying to understand basic things. Also, I have attached the flow and error screenshot.
[image]

Comment: what are you doing in the "Python"code?. It seems you just do replacing something in file right? We can't read incoming flow file in execute stream command processor

Comment: But I want to mask the data using regex in executestreamcommand processor. so how can I do it? what will be the flow in this case ?

Comment: Seems you can mask the data in ReplaceText processor itself and no need to use Python script for it.

Answer (score 1):

[ExecuteStreamCommand](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html)

The content of the flow file passed into a command (python in your case) as `stdin` stream

so, you have to use following code:

```
readFile = pd.read_json(sys.stdin)
```

---

on other hand if you need to apply regexp replace to the flow file, you could try to use [ReplaceText](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/index.html) processor instead of `ExecuteStreamCommand`

Comment: Thanks @daggett. I have columnar data. So will replace text processor be a good option for my purpose? Also, can I use read_csv method to read the data coz I want to mention the separator?

Comment: Does pandas work on jython?

Comment: @YangwookIanJeong no, pandas does not work in jython as its a natively complied python lib

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide the python .py file in the Volume where nifi has registered.

for example opt/nifi/nifi-current/ if its a docker image